Rows data before 3-4 days are empty
I use Service Account and their credentials for fetching rows and everything was good.
Now I get empty rows for last 3-4 days, but when I used 5 days before time range, I get data, but this old data-results.
I use PHP library recommended by Google.
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Google\Service\SearchConsole\SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest;
use Google_Client;
use Google\Service;
-------------------------------

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($authConfig);
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly');

$datesRange = ['start' => Carbon::now()->subDays(3)->format('Y-m-d'),
            'end' => Carbon::now()->subDays(1)->format('Y-m-d')];

$searchConsole = new Service\SearchConsole($client);
$searchAnalyticsQueryRequest = new SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest();
$searchAnalyticsQueryRequest->setSearchType("Web");
$searchAnalyticsQueryRequest->setStartDate($datesRange['start']);
$searchAnalyticsQueryRequest->setEndDate($datesRange['end']);
$searchAnalyticsQueryRequest->setRowLimit($rowLimit);

$dimensions = ['page', 'device', 'country', 'query', 'date'];

$searchAnalyticsQueryRequest->setDimensions($dimensions);

$rowList = $searchConsole->searchanalytics->query('https://xxxx.xxx/', $searchAnalyticsQueryRequest)>getRows();


Thanks to Google Community I got useful answer.
For recent data, I don't know how they check it - important to use additional parameter to Search Query request.
$searchAnalyticsQueryRequest->setDataState('all');
So adding it to request shows positive results for querying rows.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
